# How to create a Python dictionary from data imported from a text file?

Tags: python, io

I have the following text in a file named `my_text.txt`:

```
David: 2
Barbara: 97.2
David: nothing
William:

Lynn: 725
Nancy   : 87
     David:       54
Lewis: 18.30
Sue:   3193.74
James: 41.73

David: 974.1
```

I would like to be able to read this file and create a dictionary.

Here is my code:

```
def make_dictionary(file_name):

    d = {}

    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            (key, val) = (line.split(':')[0], line.split(':')[1])

    return print(d)

make_dictionary('my_text.txt')
```

I'm getting an index error:

> IndexError:  list index out of range

Does anyone see where the mistake is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This error arises due to the blank lines.

Your code assumes the [`split`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) will return two elements for you.

You'll want to check for blank lines *before* trying to use the return value of the `split` -- and skip those lines.

Also, more robust code would also *check* that the line contains a colon (`:`) on which to split on. If the line contains no colon, the code would fail. You may want to raise an exception in such a case, or at least print an error warning perhaps. You'll also need to use [`strip`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp) in order to remove extraneous whitespaces.

Your code also didn't *assign* to the dictionary -- so I've added that in as well. Also note -- [`print`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_print.asp) returns [`None`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_none.asp), so where you had `return print(d)`, it would return `None`. You'll want to return `d`, so I've updated that as well.

There's one last thing. You probably want to convert the second column of data into [`float`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_float.asp)s that can be used as numbers within Python, rather than the strings they would be when read from the file. In doing so, invalid lines would also raise an exception -- or perhaps you want to want to catch that and handle it differently.

Try the following:

```
def make_dictionary(file_name):
    d = {}
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip()
            if line == '':
                # Skip blank lines
                continue
            elif ':' in line:
                # Do the split, since we *know* we can
                key, val = line.split(':')

                # Will raise an exception if the 2nd column is not a valid number
                d[key.strip()] = float(val.strip())
            else:
                # Raise an exception if an invalid line is encountered
                raise ValueError('Cannot split line')
            
    return d

print(make_dictionary('my_text.txt'))
```

Note: Your original code `split` the line **twice** (which is inefficient and unnecessary). In Python, you can do parallel assignment instead (better known as "unpacking") -- I've adapted the code to use that approach.

Comment: Your coed does not make a dictionary. It prints `{}` because nothing assigned to `d`.

Comment: Yep thanks, I just realized the OP's code had that issue as well. I was addressing the `IndexError`. Updated my answer to address this issue as well.

Comment: @costaparas -- thank you.  I'm seeing `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'xyz'` on the line `d[key.strip()] = float(val.strip())`.  Is there a way to cast these to floats to work around this error?  Thanks.

Comment: But `xyz` is not a valid number, so what cast would make sense in such a case? Raising an exception is perfectly logical behavior. Or, you could catch the exception (with an `except:` clause) and then skip over such invalid lines (preferably with a warning message displayed and/or logged).

Comment: I chose to remove float(), which seems to work.  Do you know how I would *increment* the values for "David", who has two entries in the source file (e.g. list David as the *sum* of the values)?

Comment: Simply do `d[key.strip()] += ...` to increment. But then you'd want to initialize the values (probably to 0) using a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples), something like `d = collections.defaultdict(float)` instead of `d = {}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a dictionary, you should use a .json file. These were made for storing dictionary like objects.

Comment: Json file _is_ text file. Why one cannot make a dictionary from file containing key, value pairs? You wrote "not a text file specifically". How to make a dictionary from binary file?

Answer (score 0):

Your William key has no value.
And you have a couple of empty lines.
So, before you split the line, check if it isn't empty, and after you split check if it's length is 2.
And, you need to assign something to d in order to return it, e.g.:

```py
d[key] = value
```